# Problem returning response from POST request with Axios in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a simple post request in a Firebase Cloud function, with Axios. This function calls an API endpoint and gets an object of profile details as response. My problem is to correctly return the response to the client.

In the code below, the Cloud Function logs the result correctly. But I can't figure out how to correctly return it to the client from the client-side callGetProfile() function. (Which runs inside a Vue3 method.)

I am probably missing something obvious but am very new to Node.js and HTPP requests.

Thanks for any help!

```
// MY FUNCTION IN NODE.JS (Firebase Cloud Functions)
exports.getProfile = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {


  var postData = {
    profile_id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", //hardcoded here for testing but should be passed in "data" arg.
    profile_type: "personal",
  };
  
  let axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'X-API-KEY': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    }
  };
  
  axios.post('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', postData, axiosConfig)
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data) // this works, I get all the data correctly!!
    return res // also tried res.data
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
  })
  

});
```

```
// MY FUNCTION CLIENT SIDE (Vue3 method)
  const functions = getFunctions();
      const callGetProfile() = httpsCallable(functions, "getProfile");
      callGetProfile()
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result.data) // this doesn't work, data is "null"
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Comment: You should take a look at a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030741/node-firebase-oncall-asynchronous-function-return) SO basically all you need to do - is to return a `promise`. And to return a promise - you need to add a `return axios.post(.....)` (and `return res.data` inside of it)

Comment: Thanks a lot, just adding "return" before axios.post made it work!